# ToolbarItems button click not working in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin forms where I need to display button on right side on Navigation panel.

The button is showing, but when I click on it, it's not firing either the `Activated` or the `Clicked` event.

Here is the XAML:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="Save" Activated="SaveClicked" Clicked="SaveClicked"  Order="Primary" Priority="0" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

And code behind it is:

```
public EditDepartureChecklist()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Title = Application.Current.Properties["VesselName"].ToString();
    NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "");
    //var saveItem = new ToolbarItem
    //{
    //    Text = "Save"
    //};
    //this.ToolbarItems.Add(saveItem);
    //saveItem.SetBinding(MenuItem.CommandProperty, "SaveClicked");


}

public void SaveClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = _selectedChecklistForm;
}
```

Comment: In this page there is something working fine? Another event call or something like that? Your code seems ok.

Comment: I just noticed that in Android its working but not working in iOS

Comment: I'm not able to help you with iOS specific behavior, then. I'm sorry. Good lucky =)

Comment: Its cross platform app.. and should work on both ios simulator as well as iOS simulator

Comment: Sure! But sometimes this weird behaviours occurs. I mean I down't work with iOS even usin cross platform solutions and don't know absoluttely nothing about the Apple's technologies (and I really don't care abou it), so I can't even simulate your problem here to try to help you... Did you tried clean all, delete bin and obj and rebuild it again? You never know...

Comment: I test on my side ,it works perfectly, could you provide a simple demo which can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score -1):

```
public partial class CPage_Perfil : ContentPage
    {
       //Constructors
        public CPage_Perfil()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true);
            Title = "PERFIL";

            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem
            {
                Icon = "Editarmdpi.png",
                Name = "Editar",

           Command = new Command(() => DisplayAlert("Selected", "menu1", "OK"))
            });


        }
```

Comment: A block of code without any explanation is not an answer. please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)